# Update an array item atomically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

### Basic question:

How can I check a document's child array to see if an entry exists, update it if it does or add it if it doesn't, in an atomic fashion? I'd also like to adjust a counter atomically as well (using `$inc`), depending on the result of the first operation.

### Full explanation:

I'm trying to write a method to provide atomic "upvote" or "downvote" functionality for arbitrary mongodb documents.

What I would like to have happen is the following:

- Add "votes" and "voteScore" items to a given schema
- "votes" is an array of objects that consist of a vote type (up or down) and the userId of the voter
- "voteScore" is the running sum of all votes (+1 for upvote, -1 for downvote)

The logic I'm trying to implement is:

- When a user casts an up or down vote then the "voteScore" is updated accordingly, using the atomic `$inc` operator, and a new vote is added to the array with that user's ID and the type of the vote.
- When a user changes his/her vote then the voteScore is updated atomically and the vote is either removed from the array (if `voteType` is `"none"`), or the voteType is updated in place to reflect the change.

How would I go about doing this? I assume I'm going to have to use ether `document.update()` or `model.findOneAndUpdate()`, as the traditional [MongooseArray methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types-array-js) (followed by a `save()`) won't be atomic.

So far I have the following code, but it is not working:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var voteTypes = ['up', 'down'];
var voteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',  },
  voteType: { type: String, enum: voteTypes }
});
exports.schema = voteSchema;

exports.plugin = function votesPlugin(schema, options) {
  schema.add({ voteScore: Number });
  schema.add({ votes: [voteSchema] });
  
  schema.methods.atomicVote = function(args, callback) {
    var item = this;
    var voteType = (args.voteType && args.voteType.toLowerCase()) || 'none';
    
    var incrementScore, query;

    switch (voteType) {
      case 'none':
        incrementScore = -voteTypeValue(voteRemoved.voteType);
        query = this.update({ $inc: {voteScore: incrementScore}, $pull: { votes: { userId: args.userId } } });
        break;
      case 'up':
      case 'down':
        var newVoteVal = voteTypeValue(args.voteType);
        if (/* Vote does not already exist in array */) {
          incrementScore = newVoteVal;
          query = this.update({$inc: {voteScore: incrementScore}, $addToSet: { userId: args.userId, voteType: args.voteType });
        } else {
          var vote = /* existing vote */;
          if (vote.voteType === args.voteType) return callback(null); // no-op
          var prevVoteVal = voteTypeValue(vote.voteType);
          incrementScore = (-prevVoteVal) + newVoteVal;
          vote.voteType = args.voteType;
          // This likely won't work because document.update() doesn't have the right query param
          // to infer the index of '$'
          query = this.update({$inc: {voteScore: incrementScore}, $set: { 'votes.$': { userId: args.userId, voteType: args.voteType } });
        }
        break;
      default:
        return callback(new Error('Invalid or missing "voteType" argument (possible values are "up", "down", or "none").'));
    }
    
    query.exec(callback);
  };
};

function voteTypeValue(voteType) {
  switch (voteType) {
    case 'up': return 1;
    case 'down': return -1;
    default: return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I do this atomically?

Comment: Ah, ok, that almost got lost in your post.   MongoDB doesn't really provide a lot of locking - I believe the way to do this is to define a JS function that actually performs the operation - but I'm not even sure this gives you atomicity. =/   However, if you can manage to stuff it into a single update(), that will be atomic.

Comment: There's too much going on here. Could you simplify this question down to one MongoDB operation that you're trying to make atomic along with an example doc?

Comment: Right, I believe it is possible to do in a single `update()` (or at least most of the logic in a single `update()`, and then hopefully Mongoose's versioning would prevent other possible race conditions).
I'm just not super familiar with the underlying Mongo stuff exposed by Mongoose, so I was hoping someone with more expertise could chime in on how something like this could work.

Comment: I added a TL;DR type explanation to the top of the post to help clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this atomically you are better off separating the arrays for "up/down" votes. In this way you can either [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) or [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) from each field at the same time. This is largely due to the fact that MongoDB cannot perform those operations in a single update on the same field path within the document. Trying to do so would result in an error.

A simplified schema representation might look like this:

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
    "score": Number,
    "upVotes": [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }],
    "downVotes": [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }]
]);

module.exports = mongoose.model( 'Question', questionSchema );
```

It's a general representation so don't take it too literally, but the main point is the two arrays.

When processing an "upvote" all you really need to do is make sure that you are not adding to the "upvotes" array where that "user" already exists:

```
Question.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": question_id, "upVotes": { "$ne": user_id } },
    {
        "$inc": { "score": 1 },
        "$push": { "upVotes": user_id },
        "$pull": { "downVotes": user_id }
    },
    function(err,doc) {

    }
);
```

And the reverse to process a "downvote":

```
Question.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": question_id, "downVotes": { "$ne": user_id } },
    {
        "$inc": { "score": -1 },
        "$push": { "downVotes": user_id },
        "$pull": { "upVotes": user_id }
    },
    function(err,doc) {

    }
);
```

With the logical extension on this being that you cancel out all votes by simply "pulling" from both arrays. But you can indeed be "smart" about this and maintain the "state" information in your application so you "know" if you are incrementing or decrementing the "score" as well.

So for mine I would do it that way, and also process the "array" results when sending responses to just filter out the current "user" for the state information so you can make a smart choice when cancelling and even not send a request to the server where that user has already cast their "upvote" or "downvote" as may be the case.

Note also that [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) is not an option here without the query as [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operates independently of the other operators. So you don't want to "select" a document that would not be valid for update.

Comment: @NeilLunn Are you suggesting, for the case of clearing an existing vote, that I adjust the `$inc` value by keeping track of the user's previous vote information in the application state somehow, and then setting `$inc` to be the opposite of that previous value?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this would work for calculating the score, in the case where the user upvotes and then downvotes (or vice-versa) without canceling the vote first (`score` would go from 0 to 1 on upvote, and then 1 to 0 on downvote, when the actual `score` should be -1).